# Chrome console log dosn't work ! I need help for class?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, dreamweaver

```js
var negInteger = -3.14159265359;
var escQuote = "Quotes can also be \"escaped\".";
var theSunIsWarm = true;
var emptyInside = null;
var justAnotherVariable;

// Try this in your console:
// console.log(typeof insertVariableName);
```

I'm having problems with my java script console .  I can't read the errors or run the console.log   what is the problem ?   Do need to  check  my settings .  I'm also using dream weaver and my script doesn't have any arrays , strings or etc. 
Currently I'm trying to run console.log(typeof .....)  logs for my online class.

Comment: You need to show some sample code that is causing the issue. We cannot guess at what you are trying to output to the log to see if it is formatted correctly, etc.

Comment: just did  go look

Comment: IT worked for me. For example, "console.log(typeof negInteger)" returned "number" on the console.

Comment: it didn't for me

Comment: I really cannot think of any way to know what is wrong then. You shouldn't have to do anything at the console in Chrome to get it to output that information. What do you see instead?

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: If you don't mind, type exactly what you type in the console and exactly what you see.

Comment: I did  same exact response.  I don't see the errors either just the red X!!

Comment: Type this in the console exactly as it appears and tell me what you see: var test = "MyTest";console.log(typeof test);

Comment: same error in  the box

Comment: OK, I'm going to stop working with this now. You are not providing helpful information. I have asked twice for exact input and output and I get nothing but vague answers. "Same error in the box" -- what error? What box? I think you're just trolling me now. If you reply with an actual answer that shows what I've asked for, I'll see what I can to. But if not, I'm done.

Comment: here is what it says  var test= "MyTest";console.log(typeof test)
undefined

Comment: Thanks for that clear answer. Unfortunately I am out of ideas, then. Your browser/filesystem/profile -- something is corrupt. Or there is something I cannot tell from text messages what is going on -- invalid hidden characters, some browser extension causing an issue, etc. Try a different browser and see if it still happens in that browser's console. Good luck!

Comment: Are there filters blocking my log ?   If so  , how do i remove them ?

Answer (score 0):

Console.log should always work. If I were you i'd close chrome and restart it again, then try the same inputs, if the same output persists try and use Firefox and see if you get the same results, if you do the problem is with your formatting, in which case you should be asking a different question.

Comment: That didn't work .  It was suppose to give me the type of string it is .  Like number , string etc .

Comment: The you have other problems. If there is noting wrong with the machine itself, you are not formatting something correctly, or you have some extension or plugin in your browser that is malfunctioning. Try another machine.